# Google+ moments preview on my profile?

Tags: google-plus, preview

I have pushed google+ moments to my profile using google+ api. Is there a way to preview those pushed moments on my google+ profile?

Comment: This question shouldn't be on hold as this is perfectly clear question to those that work with the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can browse to them by going to the About tab on your Google+ profile and in the "Apps" section click on the app that you're developing to see the moments that the app wrote. You can also jump straight to a list of all apps by using https://plus.google.com/apps

Comment: And how can my circles preview those moments?

Comment: For other people, if they were granted permission by the user during the sign in flow, can see them in the same manner: Browse to user's profile->About tab, Click app, see list of moments that are visible to them.